# Change HTML normal flow

Tags: html, css

A Google search showed that this is not discussed anywhere, but:
**Would it be possible to change the normal flow of HTML?**
A designer has made a menu bar, that's on the bottom of the page. The menu bar would be a `<ul>` with a lot of `<li>` elements, that are floated left, but when reaching the end of the page, would continue upward, not downward. So the flow would not be from-left-to-right-downwards, but from-left-to-right-upwards.
I'm pretty sure this would require some overly complex JavaScript, to have this visual effect, we might just have to change the design.

Comment: You might get more joy on programmers.stackexchange.com given that this question is theoretical...

Comment: @RobbieDee No, this is not the kind of question that fits on programmers.SE. It's better off here, provided it's treated as a real question.

Comment: @OlavKokovkin I removed the bit about the question being theoretical; hope that's OK with you. See, I don't think it's impossible to do what you want with Javascript. Just check all the `li` elements to see if they overflow (wrap) and if so, give them an absolute position above the first line of `li`s.

Comment: Perhaps a mistake in your styling. Why you even use `float: left` on a list item?

Comment: @MrLister Yes, that is OK. It wasn't really "theoretical" i suppose. Thanks for the edit

Comment: @Bondye See anwser by Thomas, that is basically what i wanted

Comment: Still same question: Why floating list items?

Comment: @Bondye
I'm using Joomla. Joomla menus are constructed as lists, and this particular menu happens to be horizontal. There's nothing wrong with floating list items.

Comment: @OlavKokovkin Do you even know where `float` is for? Please use `display: inline-block;` for positioning list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you like obtain something like this:

```
Item4 item5 item6
item1 item2 item3
```

item1..item6 are li.

If yes test something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/3GLSz/3/

Comment: Wow, yes, this is what i needed! I thought the JS would look something like that, but way more complex.

Answer (score -1):

A list of elements floated, normally behave from-left-to-right-downwards. You can post some code to reproduce your behavior?

In this scenario, you can also put display:inline or inline-block to your elements.