# Float left a pair of items

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a given html that I can't change:

```
<ul>
    <li class="item1">2 lines text</li>
    <li class="item2">3 lines text</li>
    <li class="item3">1 line text</li>
    <li class="item4">4 lines text </li>
    <li class="item5">4 lines text </li>
    <li class="item6">2 lines text</li>
</ul>
```

And now I need them to look like this:

```
 | Item 1  | Item 3 | Item 5 |
 | Item 1  | Item 4 | Item 5 |
 | Item 2  | Item 4 | Item 5 |
 | Item 2  | Item 4 | Item 5 |
 | Item 2  | Item 4 | Item 6 |
                    | Item 6 |
```

If I simply float all of them left it acts like a table and the second row will be positioned vertically to match the height of the longest column of the first row. I want the items to be just 20 px vertically rom each other with the HTML I have.

What I've tried so far is to float:left; the odd ones and clear: left; the even ones but all I get is all of them one after the other in one column.

Edit: I need support for IE8+

I don't want to just change the order of the items, I want to avoid how float looks like, I will edit the question with dummy text.

Comment: That can't be done with css floats I'm afraid. The best you could do is position the LI elements absolutely to get them to line up in the way you want them. The LI's would have to have set a width and height to achieve that.

Comment: yeah, that is a no go, since the content of the li's is text that comes from a database :S

Comment: I think you should use some render templates like https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl

Comment: mithunsatheesh I need to supor IE8+

Comment: Could you use a jQuery function to reorder the HTML elements?

Comment: @Marc Audet I suspect that would be my only way to go

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246957/change-html-normal-flow?noredirect=1

Comment: If this content is served from a CMS, that means someone is deciding what goes in item1, item2 and so on.  Why can't they assign the content to the desired element?  Unless this is a news site...

Comment: It's not a matter of content but how the content looks like after loaded, it is text that will change height of the items differently.

Answer (score 1):

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yW7wA/).

You can do it via using `column-count` property.

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="item1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item3">Item 3</li>
    <li class="item4">Item 4</li>
    <li class="item5">Item 5</li>
    <li class="item6">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
ul {

    margin:0;padding:0;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;

}
```

Comment: @ElaineMarley : Your qn. didnt had any thing asking for IE support. this use CSS3.

Comment: Unfortunately no IE support... this is a CSS3 property.

Comment: @ElaineMarley If you would like wide comparability you have to use  DOM handling using Jquery or any other technique.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, Look at the following link
if you add a few `div`
http://jsfiddle.net/kUd8Y"/

Comment: Oh i See...let me a hav look at it thn and get back to you